# Uploading to a CH340 "Nano" board using a Mac with Osx High Sierra

Tags: clones, ch340

I recently purchased some inexpensive Nano boards, but they give an error signal and won't upload from my Mac with OSX High Sierra...  I am able to upload to Unos and Megas without issues.  I am selecting the correct board and the Atmega 328P and the dev/cu.bluetooth-incoming-port.I have also installed the CH341SER_MAC drivers using the H34X_INSTALL_V1.3 pkg. The error msg is as follows:  Can you help???

```
/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc" -Wall -Wextra -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.elf" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/core/core.a" "-L/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522" -lm
"/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.elf" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.eep"
"/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.elf" "/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.hex"
Sketch uses 948 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/arduino_build_850522/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:01:35
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/private/var/folders/sv/y8kh1rhd4sz23xbxsnppbp700000gn/T/AppTranslocation/B0792E1F-FE26-4369-9DFF-D54AC5E75F46/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/daniellecomte/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
Invalid library found in /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries/CH341SER_MAC: /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries/CH341SER_MAC
Invalid library found in /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries/CH341SER_MAC: /Users/daniellecomte/Documents/Arduino/libraries/CH341SER_MAC
```

Comment: "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port" is not a valid port selection for an Arduino.  If you think your board has a CH341, then it is not an Arduino Nano and you should not use that tag, but rather the clones one. Conversely, if it *is* an Arduino, you don't want to install the notorious CH341 drivers on your system since they have no relevance to an actual Arduino. Even if needed and you decide you are willing to allow it on your system, the CH341 driver must not be in your Arduino libraries folder - it is (or at least purports to be) a system driver, it is not in any way shape or form an Arduino library.

Comment: Chris...  I don't decide how the WCH  Ch 340G drivers install themselves...  I simply click to install and follow through...  I restart my computer as they say..  but that doesn't work???

Comment: Sorry, but no.  The only way the CH340G drivers got in your Arduino folder is if *you* put them there (for example when you downloaded them) or if you followed some horribly mistaken unofficial instruction or used some mysterious unofficial driver package put together by someone with no idea at all what they are doing.  As yet it's unclear if the CH340 drivers are even appropriate for your board - if they are, you must remove the improper arduino-nano tag.

Comment: Hello Chris...  I gather that you prefer Arduino brand Nanos...  I'm just trying to use a half dozen Nanos that I bought on line...  they use a WCH CH340G chip, and I have run an install app to download and install the drivers...  but it's not working...  I might have the wrong type of cable which looks much thinner than the Arduino Uno cable...   Doesn't the install app know where to install the drivers???  Should I delete drivers that already exist in my Arduino library files...  I'm not sure exactly what you are suggesting that I do?   What are the exact steps to take to make this work???

Comment: The problem is that when you **FALSELY** state a problem as pertaining to an Arduino Nano by mis-tagging, that in fact only happens with a board using **DIFFERENT PARTS NOT PRESENT IN ANY ARDUINO PRODUCT** you merely confuse the issue and lessen the chance both that you will find a solution for your board, and that those who actually have Arduino products will find a solution for theirs.

Comment: As already explained, **the Blueooth port is not a valid port selection**.  You need to select a valid port entry.  If one is not present, you need to figure out why.

Comment: Chis... get ahold of yourself...  I'm not falsely stating anything...  Arduino itself allows other companies to make Nanos, Unos and Megas, and gives them the use of the code and the IDE...   most people use less expensive boards...

Comment: Arduino very specifically and emphatically *does not* allow unauthorized parties to label their products Arduino.  When your problem stems from the difference between your board and an actual Arduino, **falsely labelling** it an Arduino Nano by misusing that tag is indeed making a **counterproductively false statement**.  There is help for CH340 boards available here - in fact there are many topics on that subject.  But to get help, you have to ask about what you have, and not the board that you **do not have**.

Comment: And for the third time, "Bluetooth incoming port" is not a valid selection - you will get absolutely nowhere until you choose a valid port.

Answer (score 4):

If your clones come with a CH340G-chip you might proceed as follows:
Download the latest driver with Hi Sierra compatibility here: [Select Driver version 1.4 !!](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver)

Install the driver by double clicking the downloaded file - the installation will stop, issuing an error message as it is an unsigned driver - but if you downloaded the driver via the GitHub link, it is ok. So open Tools, Security and you will be asked by OS X's security system if you want to install the driver anyway - YES!

After restarting your Mac connect your Nano clone and start a copy of the Arduino IDE. Assuming you got version 1.8.5: under Tools/Port you should see something like /dev/cu.wchusbserialXXX - select this port. Now update your board manager, close and restart the IDE again. Under Tools select  "Board: Arduino Nano" and "Processor: ATmega 328P (Old Bootloader)".

Now you should be ready to upload your sketch.

Background information:
Since January 2018 all original Nanos come with the Optiplex bootloader (which is also incorporated in other Arduinos like the Uno. Clones will most likely have the old bootloader pre-loaded, that's why the Processor selection must be set to ".... (Old Bootloader)".

Hope that helps to get along.

Comment: Wow, THANKYOU. This completely resolved my uploading problems with: OS X Mojave; clone Nano; CH340/341 drivers installed via https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all - until I switched to OLD BOOTLOADER, my uploads would fail with "not in sync" because avrdude was apparently getting confused by the startup serial messages from my running code.